# Why is getattr() not working like I think it should? I think this code should print 'sss'

Tags: python

the next is my code:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "a"
    def __getattr__(self,x,defalut):
        if x in self:
            return x
        else:return defalut

a=foo()
print getattr(a,'b','sss')
```

i know the `__getattr__` must be 2 argument,but i want to get a default attribute if the attribute   is no being.

how can i get it, thanks

---

and

i found if defined `__setattr__`,my next code is also can't run

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a={}
    def __setattr__(self,name,value):
            self.a[name]=value

a=foo()#error ,why
```

---

hi alex,
i changed your example:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = {'a': 'boh'}
    def __getattr__(self, x):
        if x in self.a:
            return self.a[x]
        raise AttributeError

a=foo()
print getattr(a,'a','sss')
```

it print {'a': 'boh'},not 'boh'
i think it will  print self.a not self.a['a'], This is obviously not want to see

why ,and Is there any way to avoid it

Comment: Downvoted for not listening to the answers.

Comment: @zjm, no, there is no way to have `getattr(self, 'a', whatever)` **avoid** getting `self.a` when that's present, nor is it at all obvious why one would want to.  Why don't you rename the attribute, say to `self.__a`, if you want to hide it from the outside?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem number one: you're defining an old-style class (we know you're on Python 2.something, even though you don't tell us, because you're using `print` as a keyword;-).  In Python 2:

```
class foo:
```

means you're defining an old-style, aka legacy, class, whose behavior can be rather quirky at times.  Never do that -- there's no good reason!  The old-style classes exist only for compatibility with old legacy code that relies on their quirks (and were finally abolished in Python 3).  Use *new* style classes instead:

```
class foo(object):
```

and then the check `if x in self:` will not cause a recursive `__getattr__` call.  It *will* however cause a failure anyway, because your class does not define a `__contains__` method and therefore you cannot check if `x` is contained in an instance of that class.

If what you're trying to do is whether `x` is defined in the **instance dict** of `self`, don't bother: `__getattr__` doesn't even get called in that case -- it's only called when the attribute is **not** otherwise found in `self`.

To support three-arguments calls to the `getattr` built-in, just `raise AttributeError` in your `__getattr__` method if necessary (just as would happen if you had no `__getattr__` method at all), and the built-in will do its job (it's the **built-in**'s job to intercept such cases and return the default if provided). That's the reason one never ever calls special methods such as `__getattr__` directly but rather uses built-ins and operators which internally call them -- the built-ins and operators provide substantial added value.

So to give an example which makes somewhat sense:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.blah = {'a': 'boh'}
    def __getattr__(self, x):
        if x in self.blah:
            return self.blah[x]
        raise AttributeError

a=foo()
print getattr(a,'b','sss')
```

This prints `sss`, as desired.

If you add a `__setattr__` method, **that** one intercepts **every** attempt to set attributes on `self` -- including `self.blah =` whatever.  So -- when you need to bypass the very `__setattr__` you're defining -- you must use a different approach.  For example:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__['blah'] = {}
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self.blah[name] = value
    def __getattr__(self, x):
        if x in self.blah:
            return self.blah[x]
        raise AttributeError

a=foo()
print getattr(a,'b','sss')
```

This also prints `sss`.  Instead of

```
        self.__dict__['blah'] = {}
```

you could also use

```
        object.__setattr__(self, 'blah', {})
```

Such "upcalls to the superclass's implementation" (which you could also obtain via the `super` built-in) are one of the rare exceptions to the rules "don't call special methods directly, call the built-in or use the operator instead" -- here, you want to specifically bypass the normal behavior, so the explicit special-method call is a possibility.

Comment: hi alex, i changed your example
it print {'a': 'boh'},not 'boh' i think it will print self.a not self.a['a'],

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing the `getattr` built-in function, which retrieves some attribute binding of an object dynamically (by name), at runtime, and the `__getattr__` method, which is invoked when you access some missing attribute of an object.

You can't ask

```
if x in self:
```

from within `__getattr__`, because the `in` operator will cause `__getattr__` to be invoked, leading to infinite recursion.

If you simply want to have undefined attributes all be defined as some value, then

```
def __getattr__(self, ignored):
    return "Bob Dobbs"
```